# Bash concatenating lines in a variable

Tags: bash, zsh

I was trying to convert my zsh prompt to bash and I had this line:

```
local gitstat=$(git status 2>/dev/null | grep '^\(Untracked\|Changes\|Changed but not updated:\)')
```

In zsh, when in a Git repository with unstaged changes and untracked files, the variable `$gitstat` is set to

```
Changes not staged for commit:
Untracked files:
```

but in bash, it is set to

```
Changes not staged for commit: Untracked files:
```

It seems that bash is concatenating the lines together when run in a subshell and assigning to a variable, and I can't find any explanation why or how to stop this.

Comment: You are probably not quoting `$gitstat` when you expand it. By default, `zsh` does not perform word splitting on unquoted parameter expansions (as opposed to `bash`, which does in accordance with the POSIX specification), so the embedded newline is treated simply as whitespace separating two words, rather than a literal newline.

Comment: That was it, @chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` isn't concatenating the lines; rather, you are not quoting the expansion of `$gitstatus` before printing it. If you write

```
echo $gitstatus
```

`bash` first expands `$gitstatus`, then performs word-splitting on the resulting string. Any whitespace, including embedded newlines, are treated as word separators, so that the string is split into multiple words, each of which is passed to `echo` as a separate argument. `echo` then displays each argument on one line, separated by a single space.

In contrast, quoting the expansion

```
echo "$gitstatus"
```

prevents the argument from being split into words, and the entire string (embedded newlines and all) are passed to `echo` as a single argument.

The difference between `bash` and `zsh` in this case is that `zsh`, in contrast to the POSIX specification, does not perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions.